# Passing value throught php, javascript and html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Take in mind the following; the code below and programs associated at it is runs perfectly.

```
<script>
   window.vorderby = "YEAR"
   exibelivrosAJAX();
</script>
```

but, when I did the modify below gave me the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: YEAR is not defined

```
<script>
   window.vorderby = <?php echo $_POST['formorderby']; ?>;
   exibelivrosAJAX();
</script>
```

Looking for and reading tons of messages I did the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="funcoesJS.js">
   window.vorderby = <?php echo $_POST['formorderby']; ?>;
   exibelivrosAJAX();
</script>
```

and the error was solved. But, the function exibelivrosAJAX() don't run.

Below you can see the two pieces of code that I think can help you to understand a little better.

1st piece of code in the primary file:
     echo "   ";

2nd piece of code in another php file:
    
        window.vorderby = ;
        exibelivrosAJAX();

Could you help me to understand it? Thanks a lot! Marcos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to enclose the outputed variable with qoutes

```
window.vorderby = "<?php echo $_POST['formorderby']; ?>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You still need the JS quotes:

```
<script>
   window.vorderby = "<?php echo $_POST['formorderby']; ?>";
   exibelivrosAJAX();
</script>
```

In the 2nd example, your code is not executed [and therefore you get no error] because of the `src` attribute of the `script` tag.